# Using Saboteur after Bridge in Dominion

Tags: dominion, dominion-intrigue

In Dominion I play a combo: Any card which gives me an additional 2 actions, then Bridge folloewed by Saboteur.

Bridge makes any card in my hand cheaper (i.e. cost $1 less) and cards in other players' hands, which is directly stated in the card's description. **What about cards in other players' decks?**

After playing Saboteur players should  normally reveal cards from their decks until they find one which costs $3 or more. **Does Bridge affect the prices of these cards too?** (i.e. Do other players need to find a card worth originally $4 in this case?)

Comment: Note that Bridge changes costs for both 'on destroy' and 'on gain', so the effect is neutral with respect to Saboteur, there is no real combo.  Players can still turn their Provinces instead Golds.  But they do skip the $3s.

Comment: Well, except the fact you force players to trash more expensive cards, e.g. they can't get away with handful of Villages.

Comment: Assuming you have no other 7+ cost cards, if you can play 4 **Bridges** first you're basically guaranteed to hit  a **Province**. Unless of course they're all in their hand.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Bridge affects the costs.**

From the [Dominion Intrigue rules](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_306_gameRules.pdf), page 8

> **Saboteur**
>
> ...
>
> Costs of cards are affected by Bridge